# Share on facebook wall

Tags: html, facebook

Haw can i share some info on facebook wall?
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://Mysite.com/default.aspx&t=sometext doesnt work.

---

I want to add custom share button on the my own website

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to share exactly ??

if it's a website ,just copy the link you want to share and paste it inside the status area .

```
<script>
function fbs_click()
{
u=location.href;
t=document.title;
window.open(‘http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=’+encodeURIComponent(u)+’&t=’+encodeURIComponent(t),’sharer’,'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436′);
return false;
}</script>
<a href=”http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>” onclick=”return fbs_click()” target=”_blank”><img src=”ADD_IMAGE_URL_HERE” alt=”Share on Facebook” /></a>
```

you can place this code inside your web page in the place that you want the share button to appear , and change  to the link you want to share.

for more info check [this](http://blogs.business.com/b2b-online-marketing/2009/create-share-buttons/), [this](http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/share.php) and [this](http://askville.amazon.com/add-Share-Facebook-button-webpage/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=1539369)

Comment: this share button is generated by a module or code placed inside your website , are using a CMS , or you did the programming by your self ??

Comment: @smack Im programming by myself. I just want to add my custom image which share some content from my site on facebook.

Comment: @smack I donnt know why but parameter t is not working. Just try to following to this link: http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmobilepolice.ru%2Fdefault.aspx&t=sdfasdfasdfskjndfkgljnsdfkljg

Comment: @Neir0 : it's working in my case when i open the link , you can share this to face book directly. what's the error that your getting?

Comment: @smack i havent any error but text is not equevivalent of "sdfasdfasdfskjndfkgljnsdfkljg" facebook just get text from page.

Comment: @Neir0 :  this done automatically by facebook , it will take some text from the page and place it in the share